# How to ensure ThreadPoolTaskScheduler execution is complete?

Tags: java, spring, scheduler

I have a scenario where I am reading data from database for a scheduled interval (for every 5 mins) and then execute them before the next run is started.

Below is the piece of code which does that. `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` is injected as a bean from Spring.

How can I ensure all `workflowSchedules` executions are complete before I add the next set of records to the `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`. The method `queueAndExecuteWorkflowRuns` gets called after every  database read.

```
private void queueAndExecuteWorklowRuns(Seq<WorkflowSchedule> workflowSchedules) {
    for (WorkflowSchedule workflowSchedule : workflowSchedules) {
        try {
            long minutes = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(OffsetDateTime.now(), workflowSchedule.getNextRunDate());
            threadPoolTaskScheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
                                                               @Override
                                                               public void run() {
                                                                   startPendingWorkflow(workflowSchedule);
                                                               }
                                                           },
                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minutes + 1));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception while adding workflow to scheduled pool with id " + workflowSchedule.getId()
                + " and run date " +
                workflowSchedule.getNextRunDate());
        }
    }
}

@Bean(name = "workflowSchedulerExecutor")
public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler() {
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler
        = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(1);
    return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
}
```

Comment: I wonder, could you add some clarity around something being "called after every five minutes database read". I am trying to parse that in my head, and I am not sure what you mean. Do you mean simply "every five minutes", or perhaps "five minutes after every database read"?

Comment: No it's every five minutes

Comment: OK. Please also read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Perfect got it thanks!!!